Polyfit Polynom for specific region without detected Maxima
I try to get a Poplynom from Polyfit for a specific region without any Peaks.
yellow part are the points i want to use for the polynom (these area is not always at the beginning):

    nan_indices = np.where(np.isnan(x))[0]
    x =  np.delete(np.array(x_start), nan_indices) 
    y =  np.delete(np.array(y_start), nan_indices)    
    z = np.polyfit(np.log(x), y, 1)
    #print(z) 
    p = z[0] * np.log(x) + z[1]
    #p = np.poly1d(z)
    
    alpha = z[0]
    offset = z[1]
    #add trendline to plot
    plt.plot(x, p, color='navy',linestyle='--' )
    local_max_indices, _ = find_peaks(x_start.to_numpy(), distance = 1)
           

It kind of looks like in the given image and i marked the area which i want to use for the polynom (linear). I am quiet new at python so maybe my solution by deleting the max indices is not the best idea.
So in the first step i detect Peaks with the  find_peaks function from Scipy and save the indices I just want to delet this indices before i run the polyfit function. It sounds simple but the polynom does not really show a difference to the polynom including the peak.
I tried to delete the indicated peaks like this:

    y_filtered= np.delete(np.array(y), local_max_indices)
    x_filtered= np.delete(np.array(x), local_max_indices)
    p_filtered = np.polyfit(np.log(x_filtered), y_filtered, 1)
            p_filtered_func = p_filtered[0] * np.log(x_filtered) + p_filtered[1]

but it looks like the second picture... one of the lines is the normal polynom with the peak and the other the result of these .... i reallz wanted to let it look like the peak does not exist

There is no "given image" and there are no data. This is not reproducible.

i am sorry now it is uploaded

Could you post the data as well. A link of formatted text (no screenshot).

no sorry i can't (due to company restrictions) ... maybe it helps to know that the two inputs are numpy arrays with float values
